# Issue in scraping data from a html page using beautiful soup

Tags: csv, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am scraping some data from a website and I am able to do so using the below referred code:

```
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import islice
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://shop.o2.co.uk/mobile_phones/Pay_Monthly/smartphone/all_brands').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
with open('O2_2012-12-21.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(["Date","Month","Day of Week","OEM","Device Name","Price"])
    oems = soup.findAll('span', {"class": "wwFix_h2"},text=True)
    items = soup.findAll('div',{"class":"title"})
    prices = soup.findAll('span', {"class": "handset"})
    for oem, item, price in zip(oems, items, prices):
            textcontent = u' '.join(islice(item.stripped_strings, 1, 2, 1))
            if textcontent:
                    spamwriter.writerow([time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),time.strftime("%B"),time.strftime("%A") ,unicode(oem.string).encode('utf8').strip(),textcontent,unicode(price.string).encode('utf8').strip()])
```

Now, issue is 2 of the all the price values I am scraping have different html structure then rest of the values. My output csv is showing "None" value for those because of this. Normal html structure for price on webpage is 
`<span class="handset">
                                                        FREE to £79.99</span>`

For those 2 values structure is
`<span class="handset">
<span class="delivery_amber">Up to 7 days delivery</span>
<br>"FREE on all tariffs"</span>`

Out which I am getting right now displays **None** for the second html structure instead of **Free on all tariffs**, also price value **Free on all tariffs** is mentioned under double quotes in second structure while it is outside any quotes in first structure

Please help me solve this issue, Pardon my ignorance as I am new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just detect those 2 items with an additional `if` statement:

```
if price.string is None:
    price_text = u' '.join(price.stripped_strings).replace('"', '').encode('utf8')
else:
    price_text = unicode(price.string).strip().encode('utf8')
```

then use `price_text` for your CSV file. Note that I removed the `"` quotes with a simple replace call.

Comment: I am getitng this error `SyntaxError` for "else" on running this.

Comment: @user1915050: Do you mean `SyntaxError`? I tested the code, it works for me, check you didn't forget a closing parenthesis on the line before it or similar error.

Comment: A prompt is coming after running the code "There is a error in your program, Invalid Syntax" and it highlights "else" in the code

Comment: @user1915050: doublecheck you didn't miss a `)` on the line before that. Within parenthensis and brackets, newlines are allowed, so Python then looks at the next line. `else:` makes no sense in a function call, so it throws a syntax error for that line, but the real problem is on the preceding line.

Comment: What if I want only to get "FREE on all tariffs" part not this whole as a whole "Up to 7 days delivery FREE on all tariffs
"

Comment: @user1915050: use the `islice()` trick I showed you in another post, or cast `.stripped_strings` to a list and use the last element: `unicode(list(price.stripped_strings)[-1])`. You can then also remove the first and last character (the quotes): `unicode(list(price.stripped_strings)[-1])[1:-1].encode('utf8')`.

Comment: Thanks again! You have been a great help.

Comment: @user1915050: np! Congrats on reaching 16 rep; did you know you can now vote on posts? :-)